# How to use ip camera working through activex

Tags: java, camera, ip, activex

I have an IP camera, which works through `ActiveX` (I ought to use IE now to deal with it now).
The IP camera sends data by using rtsp as follow:
`rtsp://192.168.0.100:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0?.sdp`

How can I connect to camera using Java?
Can anyone give me example of code dealing rtsp and java?

Comment: Did you try to do some research on google?

Comment: yes. most of them writes to get video I need something like "public String mjpgURL = "http://192.168.1.100/video.cgi";", And I tried it by using OpenCV, how ever it didn't work

Comment: Thats pretty trivial. What libraries did you find?

Comment: I tried via OpenCV and JMF

Comment: I checked [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239395/activex-from-java-application[link] . But it was wrote long ago and I hope that I can get connection to IP Camera without activex, because my project is on the Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will have the same problem - JMF is too old. I find the easiest way to deal with RTSP - use vlcj.
For me, the most code free example looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NativeDiscovery().discover();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new RTSPPlayer();
            }
        });
    }

    public RTSPPlayer() {
        frame = new JFrame("Media Player");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                mediaPlayerComponent.release();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
        mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);
        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("rtsp://192.168.0.100:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0?.sdp");
    }
```